# Why does this method for counting duplicates of an array and storing it into an object work?

Tags: javascript

```
var counts = {};
var your_array = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'];
your_array.forEach(function(x) { 
  counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0) + 1; 
});
console.log(your_array);
```

In javascript, why do you have to do `counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0) + 1;` Why doesn't `counts[x] += 1;` work?

This will output `{ a: 2, b: 1, c: 1}`, but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ariesed if `counts[x]` is `undefined`. In this case, an increment does not work. The logical **"or"** (`||`) evaluates the value on the left side and if that value is falsy, the right part is taken.

So for example, if you separate the line, you get

```
counts[x] || 0
```

that returns either the truthy value of `counts[x]`, if `undefined`, `false`, `null`, even `0` then the right part with value of `0`.

The addition and assignment should be clear.

Right from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy):

> In JavaScript, a **truthy** value is a value that translates to true when evaluated in a Boolean context. All values are truthy unless they are defined as falsy (i.e., except for `false`, `0`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`, and `NaN`).

Comment: How does `(counts[x] || 0)` determine what to initially set to `counts[x]`? Also, why are both counts[x] and 0 required for the code to work?

Comment: @PurpleYoshiii, because one of the values are necessary.